# Sharing via Facebook Share Button for iOS - nothing posted to Wall

Tags: ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, share-button

I am using the new Share Button for iOS (Facebook iOS SDK 4.5.1). I set everything up according to the instructions and am able to complete the sharing of a post through my iOS app. Yet no post appears on my Facebook page.

I have searched high and low and cannot seem to find anyone else who is having this problem, so I wonder if I am missing something obvious.

I do not implement Facebook Login before using the Share Button.

I am using xCode Version 7.0 beta 5.

I am testing this on my device (iPhone 5, iOS 8.4). I have the Facebook app installed on my device.

Comment: Nothing posted on wall- does this means the image, url neither the prefilled text was absent in the UI for posting from the app, or you gave everything and posted but it was absent in the facebook wall??